# datepicker focus on jquery ui dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using a jQuery datepicker on my jQueryUI dialog. Whenever the user clicks the button the popup opens and the datepicker is opening automatically. I don't want that focus, how can I remove that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#txtDOB').datepick({ dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd', minDate: new Date('1970/01/01'),
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `datepicker` shows immediately might be because the input tag for `datapicker` is  first input on a form. you can avoid this by having  another input before the `datepicker`.

Or workaround to this can be

```
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true,
```

Or you can set `tabindex="1"` to any other element